# Scala function value as argument

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In the Programming in Scala 3rd edition Book. I am confused with the code `"WithPrintWriter(new File("date.txt"), a => a.println(new java.util.Date) )}"`

```
  1 import java.io._
  2 
  3 object WithPrintWriter1 {
  4   def withPrintWriter(file: File, op: PrintWriter => Unit) {
  5     val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
  6     try {
  7       op(writer)
  8     } finally {
  9       writer.close()
 10     }
 11   }
 12   def main(args: Array[String]) {
 13     withPrintWriter(
 14       new File("date.txt"),
 15       a => a.println(new java.util.Date)
 16     )
 17   }
 18 }
```

I use the terminology of scala to interpret `a=> a.println(new java.util.Date)` in the function invocation, this is a function literal, argument is a and mapped to a a.println(new java.util.Date) function. But the prototype of the withPrintWriter function needs two types, the first is File which is right for new File("date.txt"),while the other is a function value, which takes a PrintWriter class, return a Unit (not interesting result). We passed to the second argument is `a => a.println(new java.util.Date)`, what's the type of a. the function needs a as argument and the function body is a.println(new java.util.Date). Do you think it is so weird? How is it possible for the scala compiler complete this kind of code?

```
  1 import java.io._
  2 
  3 object WithPrintWriter1 {
  4   def withPrintWriter(file: File, op: PrintWriter => Unit) {
  5     val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
  6     try {
  7       op(writer)
  8     } finally {
  9       writer.close()
 10     }
 11   }
 12   def main(args: Array[String]) {
 13     withPrintWriter(
 14       new File("date.txt"),
 15     _ => _.println(1))
 16   }
 17 }
```

Above code will produce error.
scala_test/WithPrintWriter1.scala:15: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.println(1))
    _ => _.println(1)).
Why does  the placeholder produce an error. Is it the reason the scala compiler can not infer the type?But we can replace sub_line character to any character like 'a','b','c' etc which have no type either. I am so confused.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

I tried this code which adds the type PrintWriter. It is ok. ***Maybe the type can be omitted.***

```
  1 import java.io._
  2 
  3 object WithPrintWriter1 {
  4   def withPrintWriter(file: File, op: PrintWriter => Unit) {
  5     val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
  6     try {
  7       op(writer)
  8     } finally {
  9       writer.close()
 10     }
 11   }
 12   def main(args: Array[String]) {
 13     withPrintWriter(
 14       new File("date.txt"),
 15       (a: PrintWriter) => a.println(new java.util.Date)
 16     )
 17   }
 18 }
```

While i replace a with the _ like this (_: PrintWriter), which will produce an error.
scala_test/WithPrintWriter2.scala:15: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.println(new java.util.Date()))
      (_: PrintWriter) => _.println(new java.util.Date)
That is interesting.
Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a => a.println(new java.util.Date)
```

... is actually shorthand for ...

```
a: PrintWriter => a.println(new java.util.Date)
```

The compiler has inferred the type because it knows that the 2nd argument to the `withPrintWriter()` method is supposed to be type `PrintWriter => Unit`, i.e. function with something of type `PrintWriter` input and nothing meaningful, `Unit`, result.

This won't work, `_ => _.println(1)`, because the underscore has special meaning. To use it correctly you would write: `_.println(1)`

In this context, a single underscore is shorthand for: `a => a`

Comment: Yes, your answer corresponds with my test very well. Maybe (_ : Type)  => _. ... pattern is wrong itself, and scala has no this writing pattern. Am I right?

Comment: The underscore has slightly different meanings in different contexts, but you are correct, `(_:Type)=>_` is wrong. It is sort of like saying, "Ignore the input parameter, and then use it."